# Topological p-adic vector spaces are totally disconnected?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector space endowed with a *Hausdorff* topology such that addition and scalar multiplication are continuous. Is $V$ necessarily totally disconnected?

I am in particular interested to the case of normed (or even Banach) $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector spaces, with the topology induced by the norm. I know that ultrametric spaces are automatically totally disconnected but I'm not sure any normed vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is automatically ultrametric...

Comment: In this generality, no. If you take V with the indiscrete topology, then addition and scalar multiplication are continuous for trivial reasons but V is connected, also for trivial reasons.

Comment: Right, I added the hypothesis of Hausdorff, I didn't think about trivial cases

Comment: You may want to exclude dimension 0

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen isn't a zero-dimensional v.s. trivial, thus totally disconnected for any topology?

Comment: Not without further restrictions. $\mathbb C_p \simeq \mathbb C$ as fields (with the axiom of choice). Endow the $\mathbb Q_p$- vector space $\mathbb C_p$ with the usual archimedean topology of $\mathbb C$, which is a field topology, i.e. multiplication and addition are continuous. This topology is Hausdorff but not totally disconnected.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Are you sure the scalar multiplication $\mathbb{Q}_p\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous?

Comment: @user10354138: Very good point. If one endows $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with the subspace topology, it is, but I see the OP probably asks for continuity of scalar multiplication with the $p$-adic topology on scalars; then this does not work.

Comment: Yes that is what I am interested in. Also I should mention that I am particularly interested in the normed case (I'll add this in the question)

Comment: In the same vein, @frafour: When you say "normed" vector space, does that include $norm(ax) = \lvert a \rvert_p norm(x)$? (That's the standard definition, but then again the standard definition would go on to demand $norm(x+y) \le \max(norm(x), norm(y))$ which necessarily enforces an ultrametric.)

Comment: Yes it does include scalar, but not necessarily the strong triangular inequality

Comment: The topology on $V$ is [unique if finite-dimensional](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71110/), so the question is what happens in infinite-dimensional cases.